# Filemaker Script: Constrain Found Set Using Multiple Criteria

Tags: variables, scripting, filemaker

I want to constrain a found set that I have so that it reduces the records shown down to two different values for the same field.

I've done this with Omitting records (ref script below) but after searching a round for a bit I still can't discern how to do it with Constraining because after the first constrain the fields in the second constrain would have already been omitted from the found set. Any help here would be much appreciated––even if its just a link to an existing solution,

```
Enter Find Mode [Pause: Off]
Set Field [ VFX::Shot Status ; "TEMP IP"]
Omit Record
Constrain Found Set[]
Enter Find Mode [Pause: Off]
Set Field [ VFX::Shot Status ; "TBD"]
Omit Record
Constrain Found Set[]
```

My scripting skills are limited so I know this is rudimentary but it worked for that need and now I'm looking to do something similar but with constraining instead of omitting all the possible statuses.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove line 4 and 5 and insert a new record/request step there instead.

Also, remove both omit statements.

Comment: Thank you SO SO much. I spent ages looking for exactly that.

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck.